# How to hook into buffer modified state?

Tags: hooks, buffer-modified

Such as in the built-in variable `mode-line-modified` which displays an asterisk in the mode line if the buffer is modified.

Specifically, I want to turn `hl-line-mode` off when the buffer is modified and on when it's not.

I've read the documentation about "Change Hooks", but I want `hl-line-mode` to toggle when I undo a change like the mode line asterisk.

Comment: [Relevant hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Change-Hooks.html) appear to be `after-change-functions` and `first-change-hook`.  If, for some reason, undoing from a modified buffer to an unmodified one doesn't count as a "change" for these hooks, you could advise `undo` to perform the toggle.

Comment: See also the function `buffer-modified-p` to test for whether a modification has occurred.  I am using the `after-save-hook` and `first-change-hook` to toggle a modified indicator on my tabbar.

Comment: if the change-hooks don't work perfectly when undoing, the surest way is a `post-command-hook` that checks `buffer-modified-p`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off of the comments, here are two ways to achieve what you're trying to do.  (Not extensively tested, so YMMV.)

#### Option 1: `post-command-hook`

Create a function that tests whether or not the buffer is modified, and then hook it into `post-command-hook`:

```
(defun hl-line-mode-toggle-maybe ()
  "Turn on `hl-line-mode' when buffer is unmodified, turn it off
when it is modified."
  (hl-line-mode (if (buffer-modified-p) -1 1)))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'hl-line-mode-toggle-maybe)
```

The advantage is that it's pretty simple.  The disadvantage is that Emacs will run this test after *every single command*, which seems like overkill.

#### Option 2: `first-change-hook`, `after-save-hook`, and `undo`

Create a function to turn `hl-line-mode` off and hook it into `first-change-hook`.  Create a function to turn `hl-line-mode` on and hook it into `after-save-hook`.  Provide `after` advice on `undo` such that it turns `hl-line-mode` on when an undo had returned the buffer to an unmodified state:

```
(defun hl-line-mode-off ()
  "Turn off `hl-line-mode'."
  (hl-line-mode -1))

(defun hl-line-mode-on ()
  "Turn off `hl-line-mode'."
  (hl-line-mode 1))

(add-hook 'first-change-hook #'hl-line-mode-off)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook   #'hl-line-mode-on)

(defadvice undo (after hl-line-when-unmodified activate)
  (unless (buffer-modified-p)
    (hl-line-mode 1)))
```

The advantage is that it calls these functions infrequently rather than after every command.  The disadvantage is that you've had to delve into advice, and there may be other, unanticipated ways to get a buffer to an unmodified state that don't trigger the "turn `hl-line-mode` back on" step.

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks for putting that into an answer. I ended up using the second option so as not to use a `post-command-hook`.

Comment: `revert-buffer` seems like another common case that would put the buffer in to an unmodified state. You could use the `after-revert-hook` to handle this one.

Comment: You'd also need some way to turn on highlighting for newly opened buffers -- perhaps the `after-change-major-mode-hook`?

Comment: Note that `add-hook` has a `local` parameter, so if you just want to override the behaviour in certain major modes or buffers, you can.